# How to create Text Overlays in CSS?

Tags: css, overlay

I am looking to create text overlay similar to this [link](http://www.a2zdotnet.com/test/metro.htm). If you see it, the color of text contrasts the div color, gives the feeling that text is overlaid by some outer layer of the main div color. How do I achieve this effect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used [Chrome Inspector](http://www.threetipsaday.com/2008/12/debug-inspect-google-chrome-inspector/) for you. This is a style on the numbers:

```
.metro .count {
    /*...*/
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20);
}
```

You can check it out yourself, just:

- in Chrome, right-click on the number and Inspect Element
- in Firefox, use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)
- in Internet Explorer (version 8+) by pressing F12
- other browsers also have their equivalents

[Read about CSS3 `rgba()` here](http://www.css3.info/preview/rgba/)

> The “a” in this property-name stands, for, you guessed it: alpha. This
>   new feature allows us to specify an opacity value for a color.

Answer (score 0):

That page is using a semi-transparent shadow—the [`text-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-shadow) rule—to effectively darken the colour of the background around the text. Here's the CSS they've used

```
text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
```

`rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)` resolves as black with 30% opacity.

Comment: The `text-shadow` is actually `none !important` (line 52): `.metro .ui-block-inner .ui-body { /* ... */ text-shadow: none !important;}`.

Comment: @Zeta: it's defined in `.metro .header` and the "metro" blocks that have the effect don't have any elements with the `ui-block-inner` class